# Error while overloading operator += c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, operators

I'm trying to overload operator += on a class named Movie:

```
Movie& operator+=(const Movie& other)
{
 *this=*this+other;
 return*this;}
```

gives me error Movie.h:47:10: error: with ‘Movie& Movie::operator+=(const Movie&)’
how do i over load it..?

Comment: Where is this definition? Inside the class or outside? Also `operator+` is usually defined in terms of `operator+=` rather than the other way around.

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: Does operator+ is defined for Movie objects? If so, can you post its definition?

Comment: i have operator+ and operator = , this is not the problem..
i will add the full error

Comment: Why do you expecting a `Movie operator + (const Movie&, const Movie&)` comes implementation defined after implementing just  `Movie& operator+=(const Movie& other)` - anyway, the binary operator should utilize the unary operator.

Comment: Please edit the post to add the exact error message and the code for `operator+`.

Comment: What the heck does `+=` do for a movie? Make a double feature? You may want to rethink this. It seems conceptually flawed.

Comment: assignemt in class, add a movie to another

Answer (score 1):

Despite reported problem, the code is structurally incorrect. It calls an assignment operator inside += operation, which is not neccessary and is just a performance drag.
Instead, `operator +=` should be properly coded with modification to the object, and `operator +` expressed in the terms of +=.

Comment: so inside block i should have *this+=other..?
or what?

Comment: @aviadm71 Your `operator+=` function should do what your `operator+` function currently does, but to `this` rather than to a new object. `operator+` should then use `operator+=` internally (to a new object).

Comment: i still dont get it.. what do i have to type inside the block?
i tried a few versions, doesnt compile

Comment: You still haven't posted the full error. Without it we can't help you. Also we don't know what `operator+` is supposed to do.